# formula to produce alpha-numeric list without spaces from another column

Tags: excel, list, match, alphanumeric

In Excel, I’m trying to generate a list of students who qualify for specific services but are not receiving them. I’ve been able to write a formula which returns the students that should get the specific services, a formula which lists all students getting the specific service, and a MATCH formula which then lists the students who should get the service but are not. The last step of this, which I can’t figure out, is how to add to the formula (or write a formula in a new column) which automatically sorts the list alphanumerically and without empty cells, like this:

[image of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0ire.png)

I'm all good to the third column, but I can't figure out how to make the results look like they do in the fourth column automatically. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Sorry, was trying to insert a table instead of a picture, but kept getting an error about code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're on Excel with a [spill range](https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/dynamic-array-formulas-spill-ranges/) (most people are these days), you can use the `unique`, `sort`, and `filter` functions.

Try this formula in cell D2:

```
=Sort(Unique(Filter(C:C,(C:C<>"")*(ROW(C:C)>1))))
```

If you aren't on a version of Excel that has this, you don't have a lot of options without dragging a formula and doing some odd Texjoin substation method. Most Excel versions do have this functionality as does Excel's Web version and Google Sheets (same formula would work on these platforms).

Comment: thanks! Looks like my company's version of excel does not support spill range/dynamic array functions. Will try in Google Sheets.

Comment: @jillingworth I'm 100% sure it will work on google sheets. [See here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pyaB0UPzMnwyNsrM5IUX9DoBjEcZdzelvGHyC39SdK0/view). It will also work on [Excel Web](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkDSvTvkH92hgi_mPLcvOVsNvogT?e=t0KyCE). Since you're a new user to SO, a friendly reminder to `accept` correct answers (even if the answer is your company needs to upgrade your instance of Excel... )